# ARCore – Add support for unsupported device

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I have a couple unsupported devices that I'm interested in using with ARCore:

- `ODG R7`
- `Six15 Darwin`

Neither are terribly common, so I don't ever expect them to be natively supported, even if they met the hardware requirements.

So, what are the hardware (sensor) requirements for a new device?  How would I determine if my device meets those requirements?

Is there anyway to add support manually? For instance, I'm assuming there's some sort of calibration process to determine camera intrinsics and sensor characteristics.

Is this something a user/developer could do to add support for that device?

Thanks.